# Trigger background location updates every X minutes in iOS 10

Tags: ios, location, ios10

I know there have been multiple threads on this subject, but all the answers I find seem to be outdated, working on iOS 7 or 8, and so on.

The question is: how can I trigger background location updates every X minutes (for instance: 5 minutes)? The goal here obviously is to use the less possible battery.

This solution:

- Specify location background mode
- Create an NSTimer in the background with UIApplication:beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:
- When n is smaller than UIApplication:backgroundTimeRemaining it will work just fine. When n is larger, the location manager should be enabled (and disabled) again before there is no time remaining to avoid the background task being killed.

Seems to have issues on iOS 10 regarding battery usage.

Is there still no native solution by Apple that simply allows to get background location without having the need of constant background updates that drain battery usage immensely?

Comment: Slightly off topic: Depending on your requirements [monitoring significant location changes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati) might fit.

Comment: Battery wise, does this reduce usage? Doesn't it have to stay in constant alert to the location and still drain it in the process?

Comment: Opinion based: It's the most battery efficient way to track location _changes_ in background.

Comment: Any update on how to do it, do you solve it @el-flor?